# android DatePickerDialog

Tags: android

Is there any way to make DatePickerDialog not dismiss after clicking set button ?

Answer (score 0):

Add an OnClickListener for the dialog button and override onClick.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to create your own dialog which uses a DatePicker widget in it. You can find an example of how to use the DatePicker widget in your sdk folder under:

```
ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/DateWidgets1.java 
ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/DateWidgets2.java
```

Then you can put whatever buttons and actions you want around the date picker.